# psql takes macOS user and not postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql

whenever I enter psql in the terminal, the prompt for the password comes up as desired. But the problem is that the username always has the name of my Macbook-Username(tk-first). But the username should be postgres. Can this be changed permanently?

Many thanks in advance!

PostgreSQL V15
Ventura 13.3.1

I have to write the following command every time. Surely that has to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line in your `~/.zprofile`:

```
export PGUSER=postgres
```

After doing so, open a new Terminal window and try `psql`.

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you very much!